# Correct way to include popup input in main form in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When the JQM js (1.4.5) library has finished manipulating the DOM to include all its widgets, it moves popup divs to just before the page closing div. In my case, I have inputs in the popup that I want to be POSTed as part of the `<form>` by which they were contained in the source.

Here's an illustation of what I mean:

Source:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="main">
<form>
<input name="someinput">
<div id="mypopup"><input name="Oops"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

DOM post-processing:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="main">
<form>
<input name="someinput">
</form>
<div id="mypopup"><input name="Oops"></div>
</div>
```

What's the best practice way to get that input back into the form where it can be sent via POST?

Comment: May be keeping a hidden variable inside `form` and set the value of `hidden` variable once `popup` is closed..

Comment: Yeah, the good old javascript + hidden var hack. I was wondering if there was a better way, since surely this occurs frequently...